# Why is this recursive javascript function returning NaN?

Tags: javascript, recursion

This is just the first step in a recursion problem that I'm tackleing in javascript, that asks you to check if a number is prime. Right now, I just want to make sure I'm doing the recursive part right, and I can't seem to figure out why my console.log return NaN, any help would be appreciated.

```
function prime(num){
  if (num == 0){
        return 0;
    }   
 return num%prime(num-1)  
}

console.log(prime(6));
```

Ok, now I understand it's becasue I'm trying to divide by 0. But how do I stop that? I thought thats what the if num==0 above it was for.

Comment: Modulus of 0 returns NaN.

Comment: Rethink your logic

Comment: prime(0) = 0, num % 0 = NaN, num % NaN = NaN

Comment: Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/88krsfda/), found on [GIT](https://gist.github.com/sarathsaleem/7136735).

Comment: I think main question that where will you want to go means if you came to 1 then you should stop or if you want to run to infinite then you should set your variable again. This logic always gives to you NaN end of process